# QTouchEvent not triggering with Qt 4.7.4 under Windows 8?

Tags: qt, touch, multi-touch, windows-8

I am having an issue with QT touch/multitouch support under Windows 8 running on an Acer W501 x86 tablet with a 4-point touch screen.

I have a QGraphicsView widget on which I've done

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
```

The widget's parent has an eventFilter method:

```
bool MyGUI::eventFilter(QObject* pObject, QEvent* pEvent)
{
    QEvent::Type eType = pEvent->type();
    if (pObject == _uiWindow._multitouchArea)
    {
        if ((eType == QEvent::TouchBegin) || (eType == QEvent::TouchEnd) || (eType == QEvent::TouchUpdate))
        {
            // invoke multi touch event handling here
            _handleTouchEvent(pEvent);
        }
        else if ((eType == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) || (eType == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) || (eType == QEvent::MouseMove))
        {
            // invoke mouse based handling here
            _handleMouseEvent(pEvent);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        return pObject->event(pEvent);
    }

    return false;
}
```

which is installed on the QGraphicsViewWidget.

Now I understand that Qt by default interprets single point touch events as mouse events and sends them to the application like that. However, I've been unable to trigger any TouchBegin/TouchUpdate/TouchEnd events whatsoever no matter how hard I mash the touch screen with any part(s) of my anatomy...

Is there something that I am missing here?

Thank you all!

Comment: Interestingly, I tried replacing the QGraphicsView with a simple QWidget. The QWidget seems to receive touch events just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing the event filter on the viewport() of the graphicsview?
This is where the events are sent.